# Apache forward Websocket to Golang

Tags: apache, go, forwarding

The most part of my website is delivered with PHP and Apache,
which works just fine.
However I want to use Websocket for a page (or multiple pages).
For the Websocket communication I want to use golang.
To not let the clients run into any firewall problems Websocket should use the normal webport.
(443 that is in this case - for the SSL version of Websocket).

Because Apache is already listening on that port, I need it to forward Websocket requests (or requests to a specific URL) to my golang program.
(A single golang program must listen to all incoming websocket connections, to allow for easy communication between them.)

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: mod_proxy is one possibility:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the web servers must proxy for the other. So you need to either configure Apache to proxy requests to your Golang program, or incorporate a reverse proxy into your golang program to deal with the Apache content.

It's probably easier to configure Apache as a proxy than include the reverse proxy into your Golang code, but there is a standard lib for it: http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/

Comment: I have severe problems getting that to work. The problem is, that Apache seems to communicate with my golang program via normal http, while maintaining the normal communication with the website. This doesnt allow for Websockets. There is a (not so old) solution to this. It is called mod_proxy_wstunnel. However, it is only available for Apache 2.4. This isn't available via apt-get on debian by now. When removing the old apache and compiling 2.4 from this guide http://mariobrandt.de/archives/apache/compling-apache-2-4-on-ubuntu-or-debian-519/ however, apache2 -v leaves me at version 2.2 tough?

Comment: @user2089648 Have a look at http://www.amoss.me.uk/2013/06/apache-2-2-websocket-proxying-ubuntu-mod_proxy_wstunnel/

Comment: @Intermernet Es funktioniert! :-) Nachtrag falls ein anderer den guide befolgt: Es fehlt ein ./buildconf vor ./configure. Auf jeden Fall danke für die Hilfe!

Comment: @Above: Sorry but I forgot to write english and noticed it too late to edit. Just wanted to say, that it is working with Intermernets link. However before running ./configure as pointed in the link, you have to create configure via running ./buildconf.